# How does git handle codeformat differences?

Tags: git

Just starting out to learn git, wondering how git handles codeformat differences during a merge/diff? If for example one developer uses webstorm and the Reformat Code option and another one uses vscode and some other formatting. How can you ignore the format for merging/diff? Or does git take care of this automatically?

Comment: Git will absolutely detect any changes between two source files.  The one exception would be line endings, which are possible to have Git treat the same between different platforms.  But for other types of whitespace, it would appear in a diff.  So, in practice, you should have your developers agree on a format.  Configuring your IDE the same way is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git detects all changes in your files and doesn't care about code formatting, syntax etc. For example, if you use spaces for indention but your colleague uses tabs instead, git can detect this as change.

I suggest you to define a coding guideline for your project and/or use [EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/).

Note: There is a special case about the end of line characters. Git handles those characters, you don't have to worry about it.